# How to widget test onTap and onDoubleTap on TextField enclosed in GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

Here's a simplified Flutter widget test code. The TextField on which tap and double tap are detectable on the real code contains a date time value (like 2022-10-21 14:23). Tapping on the TextField opens a Flutter TimeOfDay dialog. Double tapping on the the TextField copy the HH:mm date time value to the clipboard.

In the simplified code, tapping and double tapping simply print a value on the console. The problem is how can I test tapping and double tapping on the TextField. Here's the simplified test code:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: 'Hello world');

  testWidgets(
    'TestField onTap/onDoubleTap test',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: TextField(
                  key: const Key('textField'),
                  controller: controller,
                  onTap: () => print('TextField onTap: detected'),
                  readOnly: true,
                ),
                onDoubleTap: () =>
                    print('GestureDetector onDoubleTap: detected'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

      Finder textFieldFinder = find.byKey(const ValueKey("textField"));
      final TextField textField = tester.widget(textFieldFinder);
      expect(textField.controller!.text, 'Hello world');

      print('testing onTap twice');
      await tester.tap(textFieldFinder);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await tester.tap(textFieldFinder);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    },
  );
}
```

In the console, the output is

```
testing onTap twice
GestureDetector onDoubleTap: detected
✓ TestField onTap/onDoubleTap test
```

We see that instead of typing onTap twice, onDoubleTap is instead applied. The question is: "how can we differenciate simple tap and double tap in the widget test code ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer which shows how to apply simple tap or double tap in the widget test code. The solution is using

```
  await tester.pump(kDoubleTapTimeout);
  // or
  await tester.pump(kDoubleTapMinTime);
```

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart'; // necessary to access to
                                        // kDoubleTap... constants
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: 'Hello world');

  testWidgets(
    'TestField onTap/onDoubleTap test',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: TextField(
                  key: const Key('textField'),
                  controller: controller,
                  onTap: () => print('TextField onTap: detected'),
                  readOnly: true,
                ),
                onDoubleTap: () =>
                    print('GestureDetector onDoubleTap: detected'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

      Finder textFieldFinder = find.byKey(const ValueKey("textField"));
      final TextField textField = tester.widget(textFieldFinder);
      expect(textField.controller!.text, 'Hello world');

      print('testing onTap twice');
      await tester.tap(textFieldFinder);
      await tester.pump(kDoubleTapTimeout); // required to avoid
      //  GestureDetector.onDoubleTap: to be applied instead of
      //  TextField onTap: !
      await tester.tap(textFieldFinder);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      print('testing onDoubleTap');
      await tester.tap(textFieldFinder);
      await tester.pump(kDoubleTapMinTime);
      await tester.tap(textFieldFinder);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    },
  );
}
```

In the console, the output is

```
testing onTap twice
2 TextField onTap: detected
testing onDoubleTap
GestureDetector onDoubleTap: detected
✓ TestField onTap/onDoubleTap test
```

which shows that now differenciating simple tap from double tap works.